# AS NetStream start buffering at determinate second

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flv, mp4, netstream

I'm having some problems to start playing an external video file at determinate time.
I want to load an external mp4 or flv file and the player must start to play it at a determinate time ( ex at 100 second ). The same way of selecting a video part on the seek bar. But, using NetStream.seek, it will buffer all the video from 0 to selected second, then the video starts. But it have to start buffering to the given second time.
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be supported by the server side, so syntax depends on the server, e.g. `stream.play("file.flv?start=100000");`
Btw there's a general advice that you should seek to unbuffered position only to a keyframe to avoid display of changes on a monochrome background instead of a keyframe. Information about keyframes' times and filepositions can be found it the video file [metadata object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event%3aonMetaData)